# How to migrate VUE JS project to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

i was wondering, i there any way a VUE JS project written in JavaScript to be moved to TypeScript without re-writing everything. Friend of mine told it was possible via the VUE CLI, but because i didn't found a doc or some article about this way, i came to ask you. Did someone experienced this, and if there is someone feel free to tell me how you moved your VUE project to TypeScript. I mean all of the current code written in js to be moved to typescript.

Comment: Hey Jake, I'd recommend a quick google search.  The first results will show https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html and https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-write-a-vue-js-app-completely-in-typescript/.  It looks like there are more than a few articles on the topic.

Comment: I mean all of the current written in js to be transfered to typescript, i will update my question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just tried to transform a JS project into TS a few weeks ago.

For an existed @vue/cli created project, you could just type `vue add typescript` in command line to add TypeScript support, which is mentioned in https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/typescript.html#installing-in-an-already-created-project. After that you could write vue codes in TS.

There are two ways to write TS codes in Vue single file components: in class style or in options style. I prefer the second way because all my existed codes were written in options api, and the class api requires usage of decorators which is still a stage 2 proposal.

If you want to transform an existed Vue SFC written in JS into TS, you could just add `lang="ts"` in the `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
</script>
```

And add `Vue.extends` to wrap your default exported object to support type hints in TS.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
});
</script>
```

After that your codes may not pass the type checks, and I found some ways to fix some frequently happened errors.

For props in `data` options, add `as XXType` to specify the correct type if the type of which couldn't be infered automatically:

```
data() {
    return {
        someArray: [] as string[], // if don't do this, the type of someArray is default never[], and throw errors when you try to push something into the array.
    };
},
```

For `props` options, add `as PropType<SomeType>` to tell TS the type of this prop(you should do this for every prop):

```
import { PropType } from 'vue';
// remember to import PropType from vue

props: {
    value: {
        type: Boolean as PropType<boolean>,
        required: true,
    },
},
```

Also, add return type declarations for your computed values(and methods if needed, I don't know when I should add return types for methods but sometimes there were some errors...):

```
computed: {
    someValue(): boolean {
        return !this.value;
    },
},
```

I think after adding type notations as mentioned above, you could fix most type errors and easilly pass type checks.